# Not enough values to unpack in python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got an error, but I don't understand why it's showing.
I want to check a diagonal from a specific position. So my loop start like this

```py
for x, y in range(position[0], len(board[0][0])), range(position[1], len(board[0])):
```

but I have a message

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: You can't "unpack" multiple `range` objects like this, you need to `zip` them together, `for x, y in zip(range1, range2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the first answer. However when one range is longer than the other one, zip will only continue till the shortest is finished. If you want to continue for the longer list you will need zip_longest:

```
import itertools as it
for i,j in it.zip_longest(range(1, 10), range(1, 18)):
    print(i,j)
```

edit for comment:

this also works:

```
for x, y in zip(range(position[0], len(board[0][0])), range(position[1], len(board[0]))):
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong.  `zip` the two ranges.

```
for x, y in zip(
    range(position[0], len(board[0][0])),
    range(position[1], len(board[0]))
    ):
```